# Netbeans Maven project runs in windows, but not in Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, nullpointerexception, netbeans-8

I have a problem with our school group that the Maven project opens fine in windows, but when importing the project via GitHub (exactly the same files) the program gives a nullPointerException with an image. The Image is available in the project. The program finds the image as well, because if you look in the GUI builder, the images are visible. The following is seen even though the Build is succesfull, but no GUI is shown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at orfpred.GUI.initComponents(GUI.java:62)
at orfpred.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:21)
at orfpred.GUI$8.run(GUI.java:295)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

and the line of code

```
setIconImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/orfpred.png")).getImage());
```

at first I thought it was a backslash problem (windows and linux switches those) but thats not the problem either. I tried using google to find a similar problem, but no luck so far.

Sorry if I haven't provided the right information, I am quite new with Java. One of the school assignments is that the GUI we have to build works in windows and linux, so thats why it is an important issue. additionally we are unable to work independently via GitHub if it doesn't work on my laptop.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure the filename is valid? Linux filesystem is case sensitive.

Comment: wow.... thanks... I was looking for all obvious things, except for that. Weird that windows doesn't care. But your solution worked! thank you :)

Comment: maybe off topic, do I close the question, without an "answer" ? @user158037

Comment: If there is no valid answer you can just write what helped as an answer by yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the filenames in Linux are case sensitive, and not in windows. So by making the GUI using the GUI-maker in windows, the code will contain filenames with only lowercase letters. So either change the code or make sure all filenames are with small letters only.